# Why isn't area under curve from 0 to infinity of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ equal to 3?

Tags: integration

The integral from $$\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2} \ dx = 1$$.

The area of the box bounded by $x = [0,1]$ and $y = [0,1]$ is $1$.  For the area between $x = [0,1]$ and $y = [1,\infty)$, consider the area as the integral of $\int_1^\infty \frac1{y^2} \ dy = 1$ (by symmetry)

Thus the area is $1 + 1 + 1 = 3.  $

If this isn't the case, where am I going wrong?  And if it is, why doesn't the result of integration agree with the geometric notion of the area?  Thanks.

Comment: What symmetry? Are you sure?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture and going through your explanation graphically? What does the symmetry look like in the picture? That should give you an idea of what happens.

Comment: Guys It's just like, $1+2=9$ (by symmetry)

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating different areas. If you want to split the areas it should be like this;

$(1)$ The box bounded by $x=[0,1], y=[0,1]$ has area $1$. $(2)$ The area under $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x=1$. Now the area $(3)$ you want to calculate isn't $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^2} \mathrm{d}y$ but the positive branch of the inverse of $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$, which builds the following integral; $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \mathrm{d}y$ but this does not converge. That's where you mixed up stuff.

$(1)+(2)+(3) \neq 3$

Answer (score 2):

The graph of $\frac 1 {x^2}$ does not have that form of symmetry. In fact, if you flip the graph around the $y=x$ axis as you're trying to do, you get the function's inverse, $\frac 1 {x^{1/2}}$. It should now be obvious that the two functions aren't the same:

[image]

You can see that the graph of $\frac 1 {x^2}$ (in red) is much thinner along the $x$-axis than it is along the $y$-axis. This is why the area from $1$ to $\infty$ is finite, but the area from $1$ to $0$ is infinite.

Of course, $\frac 1 {x^{1/2}}$ has the opposite property: its area is infinite from $1$ to $\infty$ is infinite, and its area from $1$ to $0$ is finite. More generally, if $a>1$, then $\frac 1 {x^a}$ has finite area from $1$ to $\infty$ and infinite area from $1$ to $0$; and vice versa for its flipped version, $\frac 1 {x^{1/a}}$. The only case in which we actually do have symmetry is when $a=1$, in which case *both* areas are infinite.

This phenomenon is basically down to the fact that functions of the form $x^a$ with $a>1$ work fundamentally differently between $0$ and $1$ as they do on $1$ to $\infty$ - on the former, they make their input smaller, and on the latter, they make it larger.

Answer (score 0):

The area that you have "computed by symmetry" is

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2}-1=-1-1+\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1x$$

that is, $1/x^2$ is not even integrable in $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using improper integrals,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = \int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{x^2} + \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}= \lim_{b\to0^{+}} \int_{b}^{3} \frac{1}{x^2} + \lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{3}^{b} \frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$= \lim_{b\to0^{+}} \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_{b}^{3} + \lim_{b\to\infty} \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_{3}^{b}$$
$$=\lim_{b\to0^{+}} \left(\frac{-1}{3}+\frac{1}{b}\right) + \lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{b}+\frac{1}{3}\right) = \infty + 0 = \infty$$

Therefore, the integral diverges.

This is a mathematical perspective of why the integral doesn't converge.